# C# - Json.NET Config?

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to make a configuration reader class using Json.NET.

Here's the class:

```
 public sealed class ConfigFile : Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        public string FileName { get; private set; }

        public ConfigFile(string fileName)
        {
            this.FileName = fileName;

            this.Load();
        }

        private void Load()
        {
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(this.FileName);

            JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(contents));

            string lastKey = "";

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
                {
                    lastKey = reader.Value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.ContainsKey(lastKey))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    this.Add(lastKey, reader.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

It works just fine. However, it reads it **line-by-line**. That means that if I got an object like a list, it won't parse it correctly.

I have a few questions.

1. How does Json.NET's Deserializer knows how to read the .json file correctly and cast to the correct types? How can I mimic the same behavior in my class?
2. How can use the same reading behavior used in JSON.Net's Deserializer in my class so I can read the configuration file correctly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I highly recommend to dig sources of [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). 
The action that you seem to be looking for goes in `ReadInternal` method and the following `Parse*` methods.
Please take a look [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs)

Sure, you can learn a lot just by reading the code, looks like `finite state machine` is primarily abstraction that allows to handle objects reading and writing.

Comment: I'm already using ReadInternal by calling Read. However, that reads it line-by-line, like I said, which is not what I'm looking for. I want the same behavior used in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> so it can read everything and add it to the dictionary instead of assigning it to T.

Comment: You can implement greedy logic of your own. Load all the content and parse entire piece. Still didn't get what your problem was? The original source code is enough to reverse engineer all the logic, isn't it?